# Важность качественного описания меток

Tags: поддержка, faq, описание-метки

Впервые попавшему на *Stack Overflow на русском* пользователю, привыкшему к традиционному форуму, бросается в глаза отсутствие разделов. Обычно форумы делятся на заранее созданные «ветки» - разделы, соответствующие какому-либо критерию (например, языку программирования: C/C++, C# и т. д.). Такая система имеет ряд серьезных недостатков, поэтому мы используем более мощный и гибкий подход - разбиение вопросов на разделы по меткам.

Метки представляют собой карту тематик, которые разрешены или запрещены в сообществе. При наличии отточенной карты меток поиск вопросов и ответов становится на порядок эффективнее. Для улучшения нашей картографии каждая метка имеет набор атрибутов, такие как: краткое и развернутое описание, количество вопросов за разные периоды и т. д.

Пользователь, желающий исследовать проект на предмет допустимых тематик, скорее всего обратится к [странице списка меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags), где каждая метка, помимо названия, содержит:

- первые три строки краткого описания метки;
- количество вопросов по метке за два периода из следующих трех: день, неделя или месяц.

Очень важно поддерживать, как минимум, краткие описания наиболее часто используемых меток в идеальном состоянии, ведь именно они объясняют пользователям, **что относится к тематике сообщества, а что нет**.

Мы уверены, никто не сможет составить описание меток лучше самого сообщества. Пользователям, набравшим необходимое количество баллов репутации, доступен функционал редактирования описания меток. Пожалуйста, примите участие в составлении карты сообщества - добавляйте короткие и развернутые описания меток и/или улучшайте их с помощью правки.

При написании коротких описаний меток (выдержек), пожалуйста, учтите следующие рекомендации:

1. **Краткое описание - это презентационная речь в лифте о метке**. Вы можете использовать только 500 символов без пробелов, поэтому не стремитесь раскрыть абсолютно все детали. Приберегите их для развернутого описания метки (30 000 символов + форматирование Markdown). Краткое описание позволяет отнести все вопросы, отмеченные меткой, в одну группу.
2. **Избегайте описания общей идеи, стоящей за меткой, если только метка не является узкоспециализированной**. Например, для метки "email" не стоит объяснять, что такое email. Скорее всего, это очевидно для большинства интернет-пользователей.
3. **Делайте акцент на том, что именно означает метка для конкретного сообщества**.
4. **Приведите область применения метки**. Для каких вопросов ее следует использовать? Главная задача системы меток - организация вопросов. Без разъяснения области применения метки вопросы будут задаваться без нее, а в самих метках не будет смысла. Думайте, как продавец: на витрине полно меток, кричащих ”выбери меня!». Что убедит пользователя, задающего вопрос, выбрать вашу?
5. **Некоторые метки относятся к базовым разделам знаний**. Для большинства меток необходимо хотя бы небольшое объяснение, состоящее как минимум из 3–4 слов. Но если метка касается базового раздела знаний (например, любой коллега сможет с ходу рассказать вам значение метки), пожалуйста, не тратьте много усилий на составление краткого описания. Вместо этого сконцентрируйтесь на области применения метки в сообществе.
6. **Избегайте копирования информации из внешних источников**.

Даже если развернутое описание выглядит превосходно, не стесняйтесь добавлять краткое описание с областью применения метки. Несомненно, это принесет огромную пользу сообществу.

---

Эта статья является свободным переводом публикации "[Improved Tagging](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/08/improved-tagging/)".