# Как правильно составлять описание метки (tag wiki)? Что туда включать?

Tags: обсуждение, faq, метки, описание-метки

Я недавно занялся наполнением описанием меток (tag-wiki). Успел опубликовать несколько и подготовить еще ряд, опираясь на содержание аналогичных меток на en.so. Сегодня задумался: а то ли я пишу, что должно быть? Хорошо ли составлены аналогичные англоязычные метки? Выяснил следующее:

1. Краткое руководство есть в описании [привилегии `проверенный пользователь`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).
2. Более полное - в [анонсе последней версии функциональности tag wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/).
3. Часть этого документа, касающаяся краткого описания метки (tag excrept) переведена на русский язык [в разделе справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts) и в ответе на Мете: [Важность качественного описания меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/188/)
4. Все-таки руководствоваться нужно не примером, а документацией.

### Состав описания

Не хватает понимания того, что конкретно должно и не должно быть в полном описании?  **Когда уместен и неуместен каждый из этих пунктов?**

1. Примеры использования (в виде кода или команд)
2. Ссылки на вопросы, рекомендуемые для понимания предмета метки. Это могут быть вопросы, которые никто не задает, а хорошо бы, чтобы задавали. И если их прочитать, то отпадает существенная часть вопросов из следующего пункта.
3. Ссылки на часто задаваемые вопросы. Как дополнительный способ избежать дублирования и повысить просмотры.
4. Ссылки на внешнюю документацию (в смысле reference docs; например то, что выдает команда `man subject`).
5. Ссылки на интерактивные учебники (tutorials), шпаргалки (cheatsheets).
6. Список рекомендуемых книг (в том числе для разных уровней подготовки).
7. Инструментарий (IDE и прочее)
8. Ссылки или упоминания связанных меток.
9. Ссылка на чат по теме метки (для нас пока почти не актуально)
10. **Предлагайте еще пункты**

### Разные метки

Бывают как бы "главные" метки, например [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), а бывают "суб-метки", например [java-io](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-io), [java-concurrency](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-concurrency), [sql-select](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select). **Можно ли делать такое условное разделение меток?** Если да — то вопрос выше можно задать отдельно к каждой категории.

### Структура

**Какой должна быть хорошая структура описания метки?** Я считаю, что лучше стремиться к единой структуре описания. В идеале это будет некоторый шаблон, "оглавление" (как это бывает, например, на википедии). Это позволит:

1. Читателю — легче ориентироваться в метке.
2. Писателю — сразу понимать, чего еще не хватает в описании и не задумываться долго о форматировании и структуре.

Comment: Думаю, стоит здесь упомянуть, как хороший пример, метку по [android](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info)

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev: о, спасибо. Давно писал этот текст, надо бы его целиком пересмотреть уже.

Answer (score 3):

Мой вариант ответа:

### Разные метки

**Можно ли делать такое условное разделение меток?** Да, можно и нужно. Всегда в случаях, когда есть метки вида [метка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0) и [метка-вторичная-метка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0); возможно, и в некоторых других случаях.

### Состав описания

```
Пункт         | метка | метка-вторичная-метка|
-----------------------------------------
1. Примеры    |    -1   |            +          |
2. Прочитать! |    +2   |            -          |
3. ЧаВо       |   +/-3  |            +3         |
4. Мануалы    |    +    |            +4          |
5. Учебники   |    +    |            –          |
6. Книги      |    +    |            –          |
7. Инструменты|    +5   |            –          |
8. Метки      |    +    |            +          |
9. Чат        |    +    |            –          |
```

Комментарии:

1. Примеры использования для общих тем чаще всего неуместны. Для языков максимум - код программы Hello World для демонстрации синтаксиса.
2. У нас пока не так много хороших ответов, чтобы размазывать их по подтемам. Дублировать в нескольких описаниях не хотелось бы. Если какой-то вопрос дает **фундаментальное** понимание темы, то он должен быть в описании метки по общей теме, под заголовком **Рекомендуемые вопросы**.
3. Хорошие **конкретные** вопросы стоит добавлять во вторичные метки, если эти метки есть. Если нет - то в основную, под заголовком **Часто задаваемые вопросы**.
4. Ссылка на конкретную страницу документации, посвященную конкретной теме, полезна. Она экономит время пользователя на поиск по документации (которая может быть плохо организована и непонятна). Однако, ссылка не заменяет описания метки. Основные знания должны быть отражены в описании.
5. Инструментарий - вопрос важный, но не срочный. Можно делать в последнюю очередь.

### Структура

**Какой должна быть хорошая структура описания метки?**

#### Общие метки [(шаблон в markdown)](https://github.com/NickVolynkin/stackoverflow-translations/blob/master/tag-primary-template.md)

1. Общие сведения. Здесь расшифровывается то, что написано в кратком описании (wiki excrept): общие понятия, область применения.
2. Часто задаваемые вопросы.
3. Рекомендуемые к прочтению вопросы.
4. Теоретический блок.
5. Исторические справки.
6. [Техническая] документация (только справочная, не книги).

   1. Глоссарий
   2. На русском языке
   3. На английском языке
7. Рекомендуемая литература.

   1. На русском языке
   2. На английском языке
8. Ресурсы для обучения (учебники, туториалы, видеокурсы, шпаргалки).

   1. На русском языке
   2. На английском языке

#### Вторичные метки [(шаблон в markdown)](https://github.com/NickVolynkin/stackoverflow-translations/blob/master/tag-secondary-template.md)

1. Общие сведения. Здесь расшифровывается то, что написано в кратком описании (wiki excrept).
2. Использование.
3. Часто задаваемые вопросы.
4. Рекомендуемые к прочтению вопросы.
5. [Техническая] документация (только справочная, не книги).

   1. На русском языке
   2. На английском языке

Что такое глоссарий и зачем он: это список принятых переводов между англо- и русскоязычными терминами. Обычному пользователю поможет понимать документацию на разных языках, а энтузиасту stackoverflow - спрашивать и отвечать на вопросы, писать разную документацию.

Я понимаю, что голосовать за составной ответ сложно, т.к. вы можете быть согласны с одним пунктом и не согласны с другим. В таком случае, пожалуйста, оставляйте аргументированные комментарии, я буду редактировать свой ответ.