# Скопированное содержимое в описаниях меток

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

С описаниями меток на сайте сложилась достаточно сложная ситуация. Я не буду подымать все аспекты (например, говорить о том, что описания меток не на виду и не часто в них заглядывают - а потому до наведения в них порядка редко доходят руки).

Я хочу пока сконцентрироваться только на одном моменте. На том, что участники, набравшие 5к+ репутации в очереди проверок одобряют плохие описания меток. По этическим соображениям не буду приводить конкретные примеры, но ситуация достаточно тяжёлая.

Действия с метками требуют весьма высокого уровня репутации (20к для редактирования, 5к - для ревью меток). Парни! У нас не так много людей с таким уровнем репутации на сайте, тем более -- онлайн одновременно. На одного человека, кто понимает что правку нужно отменить, приходится двое кто бездумно аппрувит. И у обоих потом ощущение "мои правки хороши", поведение *закрепляется и воспроизводится*.

Я считаю, что эту тему с утверждением плохих описаний меток пора приводить в порядок.

Ниже ответ -- моё предложение, что с этим делать. Если у вас есть альтернативные -- предлагайте в ответах свои.

Comment: есть какая-нибудь оценка, какая доля проблемных описаний меток? Если их половина это одно, если одна из сотни это уже другое. При редактировании метки, уже предлагают прочитать тему: [Важность качественного описания меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/188/23044), которая явно говорит (жирным): **Избегайте копирования информации из внешних источников.**

Answer (score 8):

В справке есть раздел [Что должно содержать краткое описание метки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts), но в нём приведено то, что должно содержать описание метки, а вот рекомендаций по тому, какие описания меток плохи и их нужно отклонять нет.

Из опыта правок описаний меток, самая частая причина плохих описаний -- это скопированное содержимое. Этот опыт нигде не вербализован, его нужно описать чтобы было проще дать ссылку для ознакомления.

В текущий момент я просто предлагаю приводить ссылку на эту тему. Увидел, что кто-то принял плохое описание -- кинь ему ссылку, пусть ознакомится и прочитает. Возможно также, что многие прочитают эту тему ещё до того, как доберутся до порога репутации, достаточного чтобы утверждать описания меток. Глядишь, отложится в голове.

Нужно ли пояснять, что такое скопированное содержимое или понятно? Это когда в описание вставляется копипаста из википедии или другого источника. Лучше потратить несколько минут на качественное описание, чем брать первое попавшееся описание и вставлять его под лозунгом "лучше хоть какое-то описание, чем никакого".

Comment: Было бы лучше,если б было важно добавлять метку сразу с описанием.И если б эти все новые метки проходили модерацию. А по поводу "лучше хоть скопированное описание, чем никакого". - появляется вопрос. А зачем собственно вообще плодить метки без описаний? Лучше хоть какая-то метка,чем её отсутствие?)

Comment: Метки создаются теми, кто спрашивает вопрос и они не настроены на то, чтобы во время написания своего вопроса ещё тратить время на создание описаний к метке. Но поставить тег к вопросу -- очень информативно, например я создавал [метки под centos7 из вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/716663/213987), под [laravel5 из вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/716439/213987) и это проще и быстрее, чем писать в вопросе пояснения. И с этой точки зрения -- да, лучше метка, чем её отсутствие.

Comment: Зачем нужна метка [:file] ? Вроде как на ресурсе не приветствуется задавать слишком уж обобщённые вопросы.Зачем нужна метка [:win8],когда есть метка [:windows-8] ? Что за метка [:интерлиньяж] ? Я это к тому,что люди просто рожают метки без какого либо смысла,а потом другие участники начинают их использовать. На вопросе про "безопасность" ставят метку "взлом". "Лучше метка,чем её отсутствие" - не согласен. Если уж человек создаёт новую метку,то пусть будет добр написать описание к нему, а модерация чтоб проверяла. Это вопрос к сообществу в целом. Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: @stackflow чтобы сделать ссылку на метку, пишите так: `[tag:file]`, получится [tag:file].

Comment: Забыл про слово `tag`. А отредактировать уже не могу. Эх.

Comment: А машинный перевод приравнивается к скопированному содержимому?